# How to chain a function to end of .animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a tooltip and 2 links.

When you rollover each link the tooltip animates the opacity from 0 to 1 and I also need to change the text.

[image]
[image]

**Codepen: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/DqLCh**

I was able to take care of this using fadeIn, however I needed more options with animate, to animate motion. However with `.animate` I'm not sure how to reset the text after you mouseout off the 2nd link. How to basically switch the text back after the opacity change so that you do not see the text change while the tool-tip is animating out.

First link code:

```
$('#search').unbind('mouseover').bind('mouseover', function () {
  $('#search-tooltip').animate({
      opacity:'1'
  });
});

$('#search').unbind('mouseout').bind('mouseout', function () {
  $('#search-tooltip').animate({
  opacity:'0'
  });
});
```

2nd Link code:

```
$('#tip').unbind('mouseover').bind('mouseover', function () {
    $('#search-tooltip span').text('2nd Copy');
    $('#search-tooltip').animate({
      opacity:'1'
    });
});

$('#tip').unbind('mouseout').bind('mouseout', function () {
    $('#search-tooltip').animate({
      opacity:'0'
    });
    $('#search-tooltip span').text('First Copy');
});
```

**If you mouseover over the 2nd Link ('Tip) then mouseout, you can see the text change while it's fading out.**

I was able to solve this problem when I was previously using fadeOut:

```
$('#search-tooltip').fadeOut(function () {
    $('#search-tooltip span').text('First Copy');
});
```

Any tips? How would you go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>[jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)</kbd> has also a callback like fadeout:

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

> complete
>   Type: Function()
>   A function to call once the animation is complete.

```
$('#tip').unbind('mouseout').bind('mouseout', function () {
    $('#search-tooltip').animate({
      opacity:'0'
    }, function(){
       $('#search-tooltip span').text('First Copy');
    });
});
```